# How to not expose Workbook and Worksheet objects to other workbooks using the addin?

Tags: excel, vba, intellisense, private, excel-addins

I have a .xlam Excel Addin that exposes some functions and types. I hide any functions and modules not intended to be called externally using `Option Private Module` so they are not available externally and do not appear in Intellisense. The issue is `ThisWorkbook` and any worksheets (hidden or otherwise) in the addin are also exposed.

Let's call the VBAProject in this addin `MyVBAProject`. In a client workbook a reference to `MyVBAProject` is added. Intellisense then lists the exposed functions in the addin when `MyVBAProject.` is typed. This is great, but it also lists `ThisWorkbook` and any worksheets in the .xlam (eg `Sheet1`). This includes any functions defined in the Worksheet module: `MyVBAProject.Sheet1.YouShouldNotSeeThisFunction()`

I'm looking for some setting for Workbook and Worksheet modules equivalent to setting Instancing as Private for class modules as is the default. I'm trying to teach the addin's users to use Intellisense, and want it show only what they are allowed to reference.